# Find highest factorial less than n

Tags: python, factorial

I'm trying to find the highest factorial less than a number n.

Here is my code so far:

```
import math 

def highestNum(n):
    list = [] 
    k = 0 
    f = math.factorial(k)  

    while f < n:
        list.append(f)
        k += 1 
    print list 

highestNum(1000)
```

The code has an error causing it to not print anything. Any tips on how to improve this code so it works?

For example, `highestNum(25)` should print `[1, 2, 6, 24]`.

Comment: you have a loop that says `while f < n:`, but in the loop, you don't change `n` or `f`. that's an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

In your code `f = math.factorial(k)` is evaluated once (before the `while` loop). The value of `f` is constant (*0! = 1*), this means that `f < n` is `True` for *n > 1*. That is the reason why the loop runs forever.

Either re-evaluate `f` within the loop or switch to simple multiplication, which is preferred, since `math.factorial(k)` will eventually become slow and you have a loop counter (`k`) anyway:

```
def highestNum(n):
    lst = [] 
    k = 1 # start with 1
    f = 1 # math.factorial(1) is 1
    while f < n:
        lst.append(f)
        k += 1
        f *= k
```

Comment: This looks rather inefficient ... unless I'm missing something, you could do f *= k each time through the loop rather than having to calculate the factorial each time from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You calculate the factorial of k, which is initially zero. So f remains equal 1 all the time and the condition f < n is always true and it enter in an endless loop. Nothing will be printed. You should rewrite your code.

Comment: he knows his code his wrong, he isn't sure what. you should put an example.

Comment: i know, and your explanation is 100% correct, but i feel like an example would help more than just an explanation. didn't mean to offend. :D